# does there exist a java scheduler API that can answer "should this job be run given this date/time"

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

Sorry for the tortured title. But basically what we want to do is implement a simple scheduling mechanism in our app but we don't need/want the scheduler to actually execute the job/task on schedule. We just want to ask the scheduler if the job/task should be run, given a date/time instance.

So ideally, we would be able to do something like this:

```
// assume cron-style notation: every hour on the :30 minute mark
Schedule s = new Schedule("30 * * * *"); 
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 1, 18, 0, 30); // 12:30 AM
boolean shouldRun = s.shouldRun(c); // true 
c = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 1, 18, 0, 45); // 12:45 AM
shouldRun = s.shouldRun(c); // false
```

I see that Quartz has a "JobExecutionContext" and you can call getNextFireTime(), which would kind of get us what we want. But as far as I understand it, we'd still have to go through the definition of the job and then actually schedule it, which is all unnecessary for our purposes.

Hope this question makes sense. Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like a XY problem. Why exactly do you want to know whether a job should have been run without actually running the job?

Comment: @fge because the way our app works, we already control the process that wakes up at a given interval to do ... stuff, and for various reasons it's not feasible to put this under the control of the scheduler.

Now we want to throw a list of other tasks each with its own schedule. So when the process activates, it should go through the list of tasks and decide whether or not they should be executed during this "run".

Comment: What happens if the question is asked a few milliseconds after the scheduled time?

Comment: @AndyThomas it should return true, assuming it's still on the "correct" minute. I believe that's how cron in *nix works.

Comment: A single millisecond can change the minute value. Do you want a job to be run exactly once after the scheduled time? Have you considered using a scheduler like Quartz *not* to initiate the jobs, but instead to add them to a list that can be emptied by your existing code that wakes up a given interval?

Comment: @AndyThomas if the millisecond changes the minute value such that the current minute no longer matches with the scheduler's minute, then it should return false. We of course only want the job to run once per scheduled time, but we can handle this. re: Quartz i did mention in my OP that I see the JobExecutionContext class but I believe this would require defining the job and actually scheduling it to run which we don't want to bother with; I don't know how to find out if this can be avoided in Quartz.

Comment: Honestly, the more I see your comments, the more I believe this to be an XY problem; so why don't you take a step back and explain your "business requirements" instead?

Comment: @fge ok. realistically, our process really only needs to run once a day (i know my example shows minutes but it was just an example). There are a bunch of different calculations each of which may or may not need to be computed for a given day. We want to configure each of the individual calculations to indicate which days (e.g., every day, every monday, every 1st of the month) they should run on. And we do not want the process to be controlled by the scheduler itself (for one thing, the process could be on-demand by an end user).

Comment: OK, so, let us suppose this; what happens if the application happens to be offline when jobs are actually supposed to be run (after all, sh*t happens)?

Comment: we have other ways of dealing with this. i mean, this would be a problem if your quartz-based app goes down too, no?